# I have problem to add checkbox selected to database using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

can any one help me plz............i make this coda put the problem it's add into database just first row not all checked

```
  ` for(int i =0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
                if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    SqlParameter[] CommandParameter = new SqlParameter[3];

                    CommandParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("DMLType", "Insert");
                    CommandParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@Work_DoctorID", Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());
                    CommandParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@Work_WorkDayes", CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text);



                    dt = db.ExecSp("AllWorkingDayes", CommandParameter);
                    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {


                        Response.Redirect("?type=All");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Label1.Text = "خطأ في الاضافه";
                    }`
```

Comment: Just a note that `Response.Redirect()` will break out of the loop and end processing for the current page. That doesn't seem like the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code

```
if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected == true)
```

To

```
 if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Checked)
```

And another tip if working with booleans: it's ok to not add a comparison because it's already true or false

Comment: i'm sorry but its not working "Error 3 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a definition for 'Checked' and no extension method 'Checked' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "